# Oracle PL/SQL Trigger Error

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm trying to get a trigger to update a reportnum and suffix and be compatible with Coldfusion ORM. To make this work for tables with a single key I've used the first part of the example below. In this table I need it to update the suffix to the next value if the report number is given.

```
CREATE TABLE tb1 ( reportnum NUMBER, suffix NUMBER );

CREATE SEQUENCE seq1 START WITH 1;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "TRG1_TB1" BEFORE INSERT ON
tb1 FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF :NEW.reportnum IS NULL  THEN
        SELECT seq1.NEXTVAL INTO :NEW.reportnum FROM dual;

    ELSIF :NEW.REPORTNUM = ''  THEN
        SELECT seq1.NEXTVAL INTO :NEW.reportnum FROM dual;

    ELSIF :NEW.suffix = '' THEN
        SELECT MAX(suffix)+1 INTO :NEW.suffix FROM tb1 WHERE reportnum = :NEW.reportnum

    ELSIF :NEW.suffix = NULL THEN
        SELECT MAX(suffix)+1 INTO :NEW.suffix FROM tb1 WHERE reportnum = :NEW.reportnum

    END IF; 
END;
```

The error that I'm getting is that they command is not properly ended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `;` at the end of your suffix queries

```
 ELSIF :NEW.suffix = '' THEN
    SELECT MAX(suffix)+1 INTO :NEW.suffix 
    FROM tb1 WHERE reportnum = :NEW.reportnum;

ELSIF :NEW.suffix = NULL THEN
    SELECT MAX(suffix)+1 INTO :NEW.suffix 
    FROM tb1 WHERE reportnum = :NEW.reportnum;
```

You can also reduce number of if statements for both by doing this:
For example:

```
 IF coalesce(:NEW.reportnum,-1) = -1  THEN
    SELECT seq1.NEXTVAL INTO :NEW.reportnum FROM dual;  

ELSIF coalesce(:NEW.suffix,-1) = -1 THEN
    SELECT MAX(suffix)+1 INTO :NEW.suffix 
    FROM tb1 WHERE reportnum = :NEW.reportnum;
END IF;
```

Comment: `REPORTNUM` and `SUFFIX` are numeric. Won't comparing them to '' always evaluate to false? If so, you won't need the `COALESCE`.

Comment: That was to simple I should have seen that. Thanks for the coalesce I figured there was something out there that could simplify this statement.

Comment: @EdGibbs, you are right, i didn't notice datatypes, i see that OP was checking '' and assumed they were char types.

Comment: Well it passes the parser now but when I try to insert it says the trigger is invalid and fails re-validation.

Comment: Dropping and creating the trigger again seemed to fix the problem. Something most have been caching somewhere. Thank you both for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You are not getting the Oracle PL/SQL Trigger Error, it is the syntax error.
try this:

CREATE TABLE tb1 ( reportnum NUMBER, suffix NUMBER );

CREATE SEQUENCE seq1 START WITH 1;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "TRG1_TB1" BEFORE INSERT ON
tb1 FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF :NEW.reportnum IS NULL  THEN
        SELECT seq1.NEXTVAL INTO :NEW.reportnum FROM dual;

```
ELSIF :NEW.suffix is NULL THEN
    SELECT MAX(suffix)+1 INTO :NEW.suffix FROM tb1 WHERE reportnum = :NEW.reportnum;

END IF;
```

END;