# Coldfusion ORM Composite key not updating

Tags: orm, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I have a legacy database that I am working with and can only make limited changes to. Here's the problem I have a table with composite key columns reportnum and suffix. I've set it up so that  can triggers and sequences set the values correctly. So when I insert a new value using   model.new() then model.save() the value gets saved to the database correctly, but the problem is that when I look at the values in the model the reportnum and suffix are empty strings.

I tried creating a new primary key and turning the old key into an index but that then breaks the relationships with the other models.

Looking for suggestions on how to deal with this. Thanks. Here is a link to how I made the triggers.
 [Oracle PL/SQL Trigger Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15647188/oracle-pl-sql-trigger-error)

ORM Models:

```
component entityName="report" persistent="true" extends="coldbox.system.orm.hibernate.ActiveEntity" table="REPORTS" schema="myschema" {
    property name="reportnum" fieldtype="id" ; 
    property name="suffix" fieldtype="id" ; 
    property name="status"; 

    //Plus other properties...

    property name="parcels" 
        fieldtype="one-to-many" 
        type="array" 
        cfc="parcel" 
        singularname="parcel" 
        fkcolumn="reportnum,suffix" 
        column="reportnum,suffix"
            cascade="save-update";
}

component entityName="parcel" persistent="true" extends="coldbox.system.orm.hibernate.ActiveEntity" table="PARCELS" schema="myschema" {
    property name="parcel_id" column="parcelid" fieldtype="id" generator="sequence" sequence="myschema.seq1_parcels";
    property name="parcelnum";
    property name="reportnum";
    property name="suffix";
    //Plus other properties...
}
```

Tables:

```
CREATE TABLE reports(
    REPORTNUM      NUMBER(11),
    SUFFIX         NUMBER(11),
    STATUS         VARCHAR2(8),
;

ALTER TABLE REPORTS ADD ( CONSTRAINT PK_REPORTS PRIMARY KEY (REPORTNUM, SUFFIX));

CREATE SEQUENCE SEQ1_REPORTS MAXVALUE 1E28 START WITH 1;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "TRG1_REPORTs" BEFORE INSERT ON
myschema.REPORTS FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF coalesce( :NEW.reportnum, -1 ) = -1 THEN
        SELECT myschema.seq1_REPORTs.NEXTVAL INTO :NEW.reportnum FROM dual;
        :NEW.SUFFIX := 0;
    elsif coalesce(:NEW.suffix,-1) = -1 then
        --If only a report number is given make the suffix 1 larger then the max found.
        SELECT MAX(suffix)+1
        INTO :NEW.suffix FROM myschema.REPORTS WHERE reportnum = :NEW.reportnum;
    END IF;
END;

/

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "TRG2_REPORTs" BEFORE update ON
myschema.REPORTS FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF coalesce( :OLD.REPORTid, -1 ) = -1 THEN
        SELECT myschema.seq2_REPORTs.NEXTVAL INTO :NEW.REPORTid FROM dual;
    END IF;
END;

/

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRG1_REPORTs" BEFORE INSERT ON
myschema.REPORTS FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF coalesce( :NEW.reportnum, -1 ) = -1 THEN
        SELECT myschema.seq2_REPORTs.NEXTVAL INTO :NEW.reportnum FROM dual;
        :NEW.SUFFIX := 0;
    elsif coalesce(:NEW.suffix,-1) = -1 then
        --If only a report number is given make the suffix 1 larger then the max found.
        SELECT MAX(suffix)+1
        INTO :NEW.suffix FROM myschema.REPORTS WHERE reportnum = :NEW.reportnum;
    END IF;
END;

/


CREATE TABLE PARCELS (
    PARCELID       NUMBER(11) NOT NULL,
    PARCELNUM      NUMBER(11),
    REPORTNUM      NUMBER(11) DEFAULT 0,
    SUFFIX         NUMBER(11) DEFAULT 0,
    --Plus other properties...
;

ALTER TABLE PARCELS ADD ( CONSTRAINT PK_PARCELS PRIMARY KEY (PARCELID));

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "trg1_parcels" BEFORE INSERT ON
myschema.parcels FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF coalesce( :NEW.parcelid, -1 ) = -1  THEN
        SELECT myschema.seq1_parcels.NEXTVAL INTO :NEW.parcelid FROM DUAL;  
    END IF;
END;

/
```

Oracle 11,  & current version of Coldfusion 9.

Comment: Its going to be a lot easier to solve if you share some of your code

Comment: Agree with @SamFarmer. can you pls post your CFC - at least the properties, but also any methods you're calling - so we can see what you've done.